# Crash after assign UIImage to UIImageView.image

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

In my code:

*.h file

```
UIImageView*    imgFACE;
UIImage*        imgF;
UIImage*        imgG;
```

initialization:

```
imgF = [UIImage imageNamed: @"f.png"];
imgG = [UIImage imageNamed: @"g.png"];

UIImageView *img;
img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:FACE_RECT];
[self addSubview:img];
self.imgFACE = img;
[img release];
```

in drawRect, frequently:

```
NSLog(@"[%@]", imgF);
if(something) self.imgFACE.image = imgF;
else          self.imgFACE.image = imgG;
```

standard result of NSLog is:

```
[<UIImage: 0x5db6b0>]
```

sometimes this simply code generate crash, result of NSLog is strange:

```
[Length 4 (2 blocks, 1 used, block 0 is at 0) 4 0x146d22c0 
{ NSColor =  "UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1"; 
  NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x1454fc00> font-family: \".HelveticaNeueInterface-M3\"; 
  font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt"; 
  NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0,
  ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0,
  LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (\n 28L,\n 56L,
  \n 84L,\n 112L,\n 140L,\n 168L,\n 196L,\n 224L,\n 252L,\n 280L,\n 308L,\n 336L\n),
  DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, 
  HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0"; 
  NSShadow = "NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}"; }
```

What's a kind of object?

CRASH LOG:

```
0libobjc.A.dylib 0x3b393b26 objc_msgSend + 5
1NOM2 0x000ad7a5 -[PanelInfoView myTimerMethod] (PanelInfoView.m:527) + 309157
2Foundation 0x319a3ecd __NSFireTimer + 64
3CoreFoundation 0x30f8b0e7 <redacted> + 14
4CoreFoundation 0x30f8acff <redacted> + 782
5CoreFoundation 0x30f8909b <redacted> + 1210
6CoreFoundation 0x30ef3ce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
7CoreFoundation 0x30ef3acb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
8GraphicsServices 0x35c14283 GSEventRunModal + 138
9UIKit 0x33795a41 UIApplicationMain + 1136
10NOM2 0x0006e44d main (main.m:25) + 50253
```

As I think it's result of the memory leak.
imgF & imgG are initialized only once.

What's happen with this UIImage?

Comment: For convention (and another points) use dot notation instead of `->`

Comment: @NekakKinich Actually the use of `->` is correct here. This directly accesses the ivar. Since there is no property, use of `self.imageFACE` would be incorrect. Accessing ivars via `self->` in Objective-C is not required. It's correct, but unnecessary.

Comment: @skippy If you are going to post a question about a crash, it really helps if you tell us what the full error message is and provide details about where the error is coming from.

Comment: OK, -> or ., this is condensed code between *.m files etc.

Comment: Where's the crash log?

Comment: @rmaddy, frequently it's _mh_execute_header. No simply answer in this case, but I was make NSLog in try-catch after investigation. This is the last point of investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imgF = [UIImage imageNamed: @"f.png"];
imgG = [UIImage imageNamed: @"g.png"];
```

Both of this are autoreleased objects,

```
if(something) self.imgFACE.image = imgF;
else          self.imgFACE.image = imgG;
```

if something is NO then imgG becomes retained by the imgFACE if you are lucky and it wasn't already released, but imgF is still not retained by anyone, so on the next drawRect it is pretty sure that it will crash on NSLog(@"[%@]", imgF) or just print an other object if it was luckily allocated on that address.

Use:

```
imgF = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"f.png"] retain];
imgG = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"g.png"] retain];
```

And release them in the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
     [imgF release];
     [imgG release];

     // cleanup other resources too

     [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: thx @imihaly, I must test it. Code is big. This case happen not on all devices; with simply A4 processor never, with multicore frequently.